# com_create_guid() function got error on server side but works fine in local using php

Tags: php

working on generate a guid in a php file.i'm using the `com_create_guid()`. It works fine on localhost but i shows the below error in remote server.

> Fatal error:Call to undefined function com_create_guid() on line 6

my code is(guid part nly)

```
$guid = com_create_guid();
 echo $guid;
```

any ideas

Comment: Either your remote server is not running PHP 5, or it's running Linux and then you can't use the COM extensions.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can create GUIDs manually:

```
function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    }
    else {
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$GUID = getGUID();
echo $GUID;
```

Follow:

http://guid.us/GUID/PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: I tried this with 5 million ids each time and 5 times and didn't get any duplicates, so I assume this is good enough for business uses too.

Comment: You can in fact use this instead: sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535)); it is the identical method used in com_create_guid();

Comment: Beautiful just beautiful

Comment: @LawrenceCherone As of PHP 7.1, that shouldn't matter since `rand` now uses the same PRNG as `mt_rand`.

Answer (score 10):

To extend the partially correct answers above:

taken from http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

"From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core. You have to add COM support in php.ini"

extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

Comment: Applying `extension=php_com_dotnet.dll` seems to work in Windows Server only, not in Linux (Ubuntu 14) as issued [*here*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2614202)

Answer (score 2):

You must be running PHP version less than 5 else you must be running on a LINUX box as COM is a windows based extension.

Try this script and make sure.

```
echo function_exists('com_create_guid')
    ? "Yes" +  com_create_guid()
    : "Nope !"
;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Likely Root Cause**

Windows systems that do not have php_com_dotnet.dll loaded (check your php.ini file), as well as non Windows systems, will not be able to use *com_create_guid()*.

**The Solution**

I assembled and modified the following code as the culmination some of my own ideas and changes (such as brace support throughout), and numerous suggestions from multiple sources for implementing a cross platform and cross PHP version function that supports braced and non-braced UID creation. Specifying *false* in the function call will return a UID wrapped in braces ("Windows style"). Specifying *true* or nothing will return a UID without braces.

**Compatibility**

PHP from version 4.2 upwards is supported. It is OS agnostic and will choose the "best" method based on OS, PHP version and what PHP libraries/functions are available (including calling a fallback option if the dotnet library isn't loaded in PHP Windows).

**The Code**

```
function GUIDv4 ($trim = true)
{
    $lbrace = chr(123);    // "{"
    $rbrace = chr(125);    // "}"

    // Windows
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true) 
    {   // extension=php_com_dotnet.dll 
        if ($trim === true)
        {           
            return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
        }
        else
        {
            return com_create_guid();
        }
    }


    // OSX/Linux and Windows with OpenSSL but without com classes loaded (extension=php_com_dotnet.dll loaded in php.ini)
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes') === true) 
    {

        $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
        $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40);    // set version to 0100
        $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80);    // set bits 6-7 to 10
        if ($trim === true)
        {                   
            return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
        }
        else
        {
            return $lbrace.vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4)).$rbrace;
        }
    }

    // Fallback (PHP 4.2+)      
    mt_srand((double)microtime() * 10000);
    $charid = strtolower(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $hyphen = chr(45);                  // "-"
    $guidv4 = substr($charid,  0,  8).$hyphen.
              substr($charid,  8,  4).$hyphen.
              substr($charid, 12,  4).$hyphen.
              substr($charid, 16,  4).$hyphen.
              substr($charid, 20, 12);

    if ($trim === true)
    {                   
        return $guidv4;
    }
    else
    {
        return $lbrace.$guidv4.$rbrace;
    }       
}
```

**Usage**

```
$newGUID = GUIDv4([false]);  // false for braces, true or nothing for no braces
```

---

**More Information**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

http://php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

http://guid.us/GUID/PHP

Answer (score -1):

I am using this instead of com_create_guid :

```
function guid() {
    sprintf('%04X%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X-%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), 
mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 
49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
}
```

The sprintf function constructs a formatted string by taking a format string and variables. Therefore a pattern is specified in the first parameter of sprintf. Within the format string, format specifiers like %04X are used. These specifiers indicate displaying hexadecimal numbers with a width of four characters. Then I set a random number for each %04X. I end up with a value like this: B74566FD-85B3-490E-9159-DE7F6C7CD706

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Of course, thanks for your reply. The sprintf function constructs a formatted string by taking a format string and variables. Therefore a pattern is specified in the first parameter of sprintf. Within the format string, format specifiers like %04X are used. These specifiers indicate displaying hexadecimal numbers with a width of four characters. Then I set a random number for each %04X.
I end up with a value like this: B74566FD-85B3-490E-9159-DE7F6C7CD706

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it, not to the comment section. I don't see how your code resolves the given error message after all

Comment: You still haven't explained how your answer relates to the initial problem. Wouldn't `$guid = com_create_guid();` still return the same error message?

Comment: Rather than a solution to the first problem, I suggested a way to create a guid as an alternative to the com_create_guid.