# Why would a PHP library function vanish?

Tags: php, com, guid

I got a panicked call from a little non-profit telling me that users could no longer register. I poked the form processor and found that it died on this gem:

```
$uid = trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');
```

That line of code has been doing it's job for 4 years. I dropped this into the page:

```
function_exists('com_create_guid')
```

... and that told me that it no longer existed. Judging from the dates in the database, the last time this functioned was June 3 (it's now July 2). I got in touch with the ISP's support and got moved through three tiers until I got to an actual programmer. He had me change PHP versions and enable a few likely things, but the function remained gone. I have since moved on to a workaround, but I wondered if anyone knew why this would just simply go away. (And I know someone will ask who the ISP is, so I'll note that it's GoDaddy.)

Comment: That is apparently only a windows-based function, is this a windows server? If so, I wonder if a possible windows update (in the .Net realm) changed something. What PHP version is in use? Heck I have Windows 10, and the interactive shell says that the function does not exist, and I have PHP v7.1.1 ... I did cross [this info at PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php), if it may have any relevance.

Comment: I'm going to note that I'm not a regular PHP programmer. The server is GoDaddy's, so I can't answer questions about it. At the tech's suggestion, I tried version 5 and 7. According to the documentation, com_create_guid is supported by both. Your link is probably the best information I have. I will go take a look at the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

A quite similar issue was discussed here: [com_create_guid() function got error on server side but works fine in local using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206851/com-create-guid-function-got-error-on-server-side-but-works-fine-in-local-usin)

As it was mentioned in the comments, seems that COM extension was disabled or removed from Windows.

Try to replace with that one from [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)

```
function guidv4()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid') === true)
        return trim(com_create_guid(), '{}');

    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
```

Comment: As I noted in my question, I already had a work-around. Another workaround is interesting, but it doesn't answer the question of why the original function stopped working after 3-4 years.